# Correctly shutdown a CVDisplayLink

Tags: cocoa, opengl

I am writing a Cocoa OpenGL app and running my main loop with a `CVDisplayLink` per [this technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2004/qa1385.html). It works fine for running the loop.

The problem is that sometimes when I quit, my display link callback will be called on its own thread after my application has already quit. This causes my rendering code to get called and crash as soon as I call any OpenGL function (`glClear` in this case), because my context no longer exists.

I have `CVDisplayLinkRelease(displayLink);` in my NSView's `dealloc` function, but it never seems to get called, I'm assuming because of ARC. Is there someway I can ensure that my display link is destroyed before my view?

**Edit:** I didn't notice the crash is actually being triggered by an assert I have. I assert on `glGetError` after each OpenGL call I make to make sure I can catch bugs early. After a call to `glClear` or `[[view openGLContext] flushBuffer];` I get error 1286, which is `GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION`.

That makes logical sense because my window and thus view are being deallocated, but it doesn't help the problem. I don't want to just ignore those errors because they could obviously happen in more cases than just this. I still need to find the "right" way to ensure my display link is shut down before my view.

Comment: Do you use `CVDisplayLinkStop()` at some point in your quitting code? I use that here in my termination code and I don't think I've seen a callback after that point once.

Comment: @BradLarson: I have it in my view's `dealloc` function, which doesn't get called with ARC. Based on Apple's documentation, it looks like the right place to start the link is in my `prepareOpenGL` function, which is a member of the view. Assuming thats the case, I'd also like to stop the link as part of the view too. Is there a function in the view that is automatically called before it gets autoreleased?

Comment: `-dealloc` should still be getting called under ARC. It was only with garbage collection that it wasn't. You should be safe in placing it there, as long as your view is being properly deallocated. If your view's `-dealloc` isn't being called at all, you may have another problem on your hands.

Comment: @BradLarson: So the way I handle deallocating my view is by not doing anything. As it stands right now, I do nothing when I quit my app. My main window is created programmatically, as is my view. The window should be autoreleased on quit, in turn autoreleasing my view. But it doesn't appear to do that. I put a breakpoint in my view's `dealloc` and it never gets hit. Do I have to do something to trigger a release of my window?

Comment: @BradLarson: For reference, here's my allocation code in my app delegate: `[self setWindow:[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask 
backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered 
defer:NO]];
[[self window] setContentView:[[MyOpenGLView alloc] init]];`

Comment: Do you use `-close` on your NSWindow or NSWindowController when you exit? Is it possible there's a retain loop somewhere in there (strong link from window to window controller, etc.)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13190/discussion-between-kyle-and-brad-larson)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an application terminates, nothing in its autorelease pool gets released—the application simply `exit`s and lets the operating system clean up the memory. Since nothing gets released, nothing receives a `dealloc` message.

This means two things:

- You should not tie the lifetime of files, connections, or anything else that does not solely reside in memory to the lifetime of an object.
- You should ensure that you end those things' lifetimes in response to termination as well as deallocation.

There are two ways to handle termination. The way I usually do it in a single-window app is by having my application's delegate be nothing else, and directly own my primary window controller. The other way is to add yourself as an observer for the `NSApplicationWillTerminate` notification and respond to it by, e.g., stopping your display link.

If any part of your cleanup may take some time, your application's delegate should respond to `applicationShouldTerminate:` by returning `NSTerminateLater`, and you should send the application a `replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:` message when you're done with whatever you needed to do.

The other solution to the original problem—your CVDisplayLink callback getting called before you have a chance to close the link—is the complete opposite: Enable [sudden termination](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW22). When that is enabled, your application will quit by sending itself `SIGKILL` (better known by the command-line invocation `kill -9`), which means that every one of your threads *will* stop immediately.

Of course, if you have anything that really does need to be cleaned up (lock files, network connections, etc.), then you should disable sudden termination around those things' lifetime, and be prepared for regular termination during that time.